# Printing time to binary file in C# .net

Tags: c#, .net

I got this next problem.
I have a binary file, which I write to it vital data of the system.
One of the fields is time, which I use DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmssffffff), in format of microseconds. This data (in a string) I convert (to ToCahrArray) (and checked it in debugging in it is fine), it consists of time valid till the microseconds.
Then I write it and flush it to the file. When opening it with PsPad that translate binary to Ascii, I see that data is corrupted in this field and a nother one but the rest of the message is fine.

**The code:**

```
void Write(string strData) {
   char[] cD = strData.ToCharArry();
   bw.Write(c); //br is from type of BinaryWriter 
   bw.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you writing text data to a text file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're writing out the bytes in Unicode characters, not Ascii bytes.  If you want Ascii bytes, you should change this to use the [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) class.

```
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strData);
bw.Write(data);
```

I strongly recommend reading [Joel Spolsky's article on character sets and encoding](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).  It may help you understand what your current code is not working properly.

Comment: +1 for the reference to Joel's article -- it should be required reading!